# Regular expression to read only digits after last slash

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to read the numbers after the last \ using regular expressions but unable to do it.

I've tried using `[^\\]*$`, `([^/]+$)` but both don't work. The first one removes the numbers.

Please can you advice?

My sample data is:

```
C:\Users\Documents\Projects\Austraila\Customer\Organisation\176276
```

Comment: Which language/regex engine? What do you mean by ‘*read*’? Capture? Replace? And you do know that forward-slash and back-slash are different characters, right?

Comment: What is your sample data?

Comment: How do you think we can get to your data?

Comment: @Arkej It's probably the path itself.

Comment: sorry for confusion. My sample data is the string with the path. I want to read the numbers after the last slash. So my variable should just display the numbers. Hope I am clearer now. JavaScript.

Comment: You may just use `/\\([0-9]+)$/` and grab Group 1 contents.

Comment: Is regular expression the only option for you(by requirement?) ? What language do you want/need to use?

Comment: @EricDavid This smells like an [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). Do you simply want to get the filename part of a path?

Comment: I am using LUA, so the best would be in LUA. However LUA uses more of a pattern matching style. I only need to get the filename @Biffen

Comment: @EricDavid **1** [You should have told us about the *actual* problem from the start.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) You should just use a function to get the filename. Forget about regex. **2** It's Lua now? Why did you say JavaScript before?

Comment: @Biffen, my sincere apologies, my script editor allows to use javascript too. So trying with both ways.

Comment: @EricDavid Please [edit] the question to describe the *actual* problem. And give it the proper tags.

Comment: @Biffen, thanks. You are right. got the idea from there.. and used Wiktor's solution. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JS, you may use

```
/\\(\d+)$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yod59E/1)

The `\\(\d+)$` regex matches:

- `\\` - a literal `\` symbol
- `(\d+)` - Group 1: one or more digits
- `$` - end of string.

```js
var path = "C:\\Users\\Documents\\Projects\\Austraila\\Customer\\Organisation\\176276";
var m = path.match(/\\(\d+)$/);
if (m) {
  console.log(m[1]);
}
```

[**Lua solution**](https://ideone.com/qv7QIm):

```
print(
    string.match(
        [[C:\Users\Documents\Projects\Austraila\Customer\Organisation\176276]], 
        [[\(%d+)$]]
    )
)
```

Comment: Note that in case there are chars other than digits at the end, you can use a negated character class based regex like `/\\([^\\]+)$/`. The `[^\\]+` will match 1 or more symbols other than ``\``.

Comment: I added a Lua pattern solution. Basically, it is the same, just `\d` must be changed into `%d` Lua pattern, and `string.match` returns the list of captured values if they are defined in the pattern. Since there is  1 capture group, the result is the digits at the end.

Answer (score 0):

If, and only if, you're having this structure all the time, you can also use the `.split()` (OP mentioned JavaScript in the tags, so i'm providing this alternative as an answer).

```
var url = "C:\Users\Documents\Projects\Austraila\Customer\Organisation\176276";
var split = url.split("\"); /* Divides the string into an array which is splitted by \ */
var item = url[url.length - 1] /* Grab the last value in the array (176276) */

console.log(item)
// Prints 176276
```